# Does it converge?

Tags: integration

I have no idea of how to start this problem below to test if it converges. 
Any hints and recommendations will be greatly appreciated!

$$\int_3^\infty\frac{x^2-\sqrt{x}}{x^3-3\cos^2 x}dx$$

[Integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7P03.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

First, for $x \ge 3$,
$$x^3-3\cos^2 x \ne 0$$
Then
$$\frac{x^2-\sqrt{x}}{x^3-3\cos^2 x}\ge \frac{x^2-\sqrt{x}}{x^3}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^{5/2}}$$
So the lower bound of the integral is
$$\int_3^\infty\frac{1}{x}dx-\int_3^\infty\frac{1}{x^{5/2}}dx$$

Since the second integral converge and the first integral does not. So your integral does not converge.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The integral is greater than the integral $\int_{3}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}-\sqrt{x}}{x^{3}}dx$  and this clearly grows like $\int 1/x \ dx$ which diverges.

Comment: Thank you! So the justification for concluding that my integral also diverges is the comparison test, correct? Since it's greater than an integral that diverges.

Comment: Yes, that's the standard use of the comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: Compare it with $\displaystyle \int_{3}^\infty \dfrac{1}{x}dx$

Comment: Alright, I know that this integral does not converge